# How can I avoid hardcoding `Log` tags in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In the days of Fragments and Views, I would write Log statements like so:

```
val Any.TAG: String
  get() = javaClass.simpleName

class MyFragment : Fragment() {
  ...
  Log.v(TAG, "Something")
}
```

This worked great to avoid having to hardcode a `TAG` for every Fragment or View. In fact, it worked for any class!

With the dawn of Compose, Fragments and Views have been replaced with `@Composable` functions. But I can't use my `TAG` utility in a function!

Is there a nice way to generate a TAG for each of my `@Composable`s? Something based on the function name would be great, but I'm not sure if that information is available at run-time.

Comment: You can use the ready made android studio live templates. Just type `logt`, `logd`, `loge` etc to load them.

Comment: This is a good time-saving suggestion for solving the other part of the problem, but `logd` and `loge` still require that I hardcode a `TAG` variable somewhere in my function. `logt` would be most useful, but it's not available in Composable functions (because it requires a class name)

Comment: Thanks, these are good ideas. I ended up also creating my own live template which auto-fills `val TAG = "$METHOD_NAME$"`, which then lets me use the existing `logd`, `loge` templates without any tweaking.

Comment: You can try this logger: https://github.com/orhanobut/logger. It will do what you are asking plus more.

Comment: @AtickFaisal, AFAICS It provides a constant Tag `PRETTY_LOGGER` or a customizable TAG which we have to provide. Correct me if that is not the case.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Yes, the tag is fixed. But it also prints class and method names. You can customize everything according to your needs.